# How to protect PE file resources(string,image....)?

Tags: resources, editing, portable-executable

I need any method to protect pe file resources form editing and thank you very much..

editing like:

1) open pe file as binary file and search about a string then edit it.

or

2) edit assembly code like "jne"(jumb if not equal) to "je"(jumb if equal)

```
                        **best regards**
```

Answer (score 2):

Use exe packer. There are plenty of them, so I'm sure you'll have no problem to pick one that suits your needs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression

Answer (score 0):

If that's a commercial application and you are willing to spend some money on good protection, consider Themida: http://www.themida.com/